# clear read only variables from perl regexp

Tags: regex, perl

Have a bit of an issue trying to clear a read-only variable in Perl regexp.
Here is a sample code.

```
while (<$input>) {
    $cap = "";
    $_ =~ s/(.*)"(hello)(.*)"(.*)/$1$2$4/;
    $cap = $2;
    print "$_\n";
    print "captured $cap\n";
}
```

This is fine until the line it's reading does not have hello. 
For some reason even if regexp didn't match anything, $2 still remains as "hello".
I tried using

```
$2 = "";
```

But I get a

> Modification of a read-only value attempted

Any suggestions on how to clear the variable?

Comment: Read-only values can't be modified. That is kind of the point! Note that the substitution will not take place if the match does not occur, though.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than clearing the variable, check if the match was successful:

```
while (<$input>) {
    $cap = "";
    if ($_ =~ s/(.*)"(hello)(.*)"(.*)/$1$2$4/) {
        $cap = $2;
    }
    print "$_\n";
    print "captured $cap\n";
}
```